# How to remove duplicates in Enumerable.Zip extension method c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two List, which I'm merging using ZIP

```
List<long> id = new List<long>();
List<long> requester = new List<long>();
id.Add(101);
id.Add(102);
id.Add(103);
id.Add(101);
requester.Add(100);
requester.Add(200);
requester.Add(200);
requester.Add(100);
var numbersAndWords = id.Zip(requester, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
```

Is there any way to remove duplicates values in numbersAndWords?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to call `Distinct()` on the result.

Comment: `var numbersAndWords = id.Zip(requester, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w }).Distinct()`;

Comment: Why you don't create a class `Request` with properties like `Id`/`Number` and `RequesterWord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id.Zip(requester, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w }).Distinct();
```

The anonymous class that is generated by the compiler gets an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method which consider all the properties, so `Distinct` should perfectly work for your purpose.

Additionally, `Distinct` does not change the order, it only removes the duplicates, if this matters to you.